# Why are autoboxed Integers and .getClass() values ==-equal, not only .equals()-equal?

Tags: java, equals

Maybe I've been working too long on Java without really understanding some of its basics.
I do understand that `==` is for object reference equality and `.equals()` is for object value equality.

1. Comparing `Integers`:

   ```
   Integer x = 1, y = 1;  
   System.out.println(x == y); // true
   ```

   Why? Since object reference equality is used, it should be false since they are both different objects.
2. Comparing `getClass()` return values:

   ```
   String s1 = "a", s2 = "b";  
   System.out.println(s1.getClass() == s2.getClass()); // true
   ```

   Why? Again as per above, object reference is used. Both using `getClass` will return separate Class objects.

Did I miss something or is my mind is too tired of coding in Java?

Comment: Why do you thing the `getClass` call should return different objects? Both `s1` and `s2` are of class `String` so it's rather natural that `getClass` should return the _same_ class object.

Comment: Because the getClass() does not return object of String class but rather of Class class. Well the getClass actually return an object of Class<? extends |T|> which is of Class object.

Comment: Yes getClass gives you a reference to an object of Class class. Why would these to references you get _not_ be the same when they represent the _same_ class (String here)?

Comment: Try, with your example code, `x.getClass() == s1.getClass()`. This will return false, because x and s1 are of different classes, so the Class object returned by getClass() is a different one. The fact that Integer and String both have "special" handling with pooling is unrelated.

Comment: YES! That's the idea. (But, and that's not important in usual circumstances, there _can_ be multiple instances of a class for the same type in the same VM: when multiple ClassLoaders are involved. In the normal case, as long as you're not playing with classloaders yourself, this will not happen.)

Comment: Ok. I see what you are saying. No point to have separate object of the same class anyway.

Comment: Actually, for `Class`-objects, `.equals()` and `==` do exactly the same (as its `.equals()` method is not overridden from `Object`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Integer objects

```
Integer x = 1, y = 1;
System.out.println(x==y); // true, why?
```

This happens because for values in the `byte` range (-128 to +127), java uses cached Integer objects, stored in [Integer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)'s inner class, [IntegerCache](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/java/lang/Integer%24IntegerCache.html). Every time an Integer object is created with value between -128 and +127, the *same object* will be returned (instead of creating the *new* object).

Conversely, for values *outside* the `byte` range, the comparison is `false`:

```
Integer x = 999, y = 999;
System.out.println(x==y); // false
```

#### Class objects

```
String s1 = "a", s2 = "b";
System.out.println(s1.getClass() == s2.getClass()); // true. Why?
```

This is true because the *class* of both objects is `String`, and there is only one copy of each class object per JVM (it's like a singleton). The *class object* returned from `getClass()` of each String is *the same* class object (`String.class`).

Comment: Actually the last sentence isn't really true. You can get more than one string class (and GREAT compile errors) if you play with classloaders the wrong way. Still +1, but a bit nitpicking is just too much fun to ressist ;)

Comment: @Bohemian Try this. ArrayList <Integer> x1 = new ArrayList <Integer>() and  ArrayList <Integer> x2 = new ArrayList <<Integer>() and do a printout of the getClass() of both x1 and x2 using ==. It will print TRUE. Now that is not of String class.

Comment: @yapkm01 Yeah obviously. There's only one ArrayList class. What the arraylist is unimportant too when comparing classes (generics being not available at runtime)

Comment: @yapkm01 Now you are comparing the classes of `ArrayList` - yes they are the same object `ArrayList.class`

Comment: @Philipp Reichart Ah yep obviously - how did that happen... the errors confused me!

Comment: This thing about Integer within byte range being cached trick is never mentioned in any SCJP books. Gee ..

Comment: "Every time an Integer object is created with value between -128 and +127, the same object will be returned" -- this is not true. It only holds true if the new Integer object is created with the `Integer.valueOf(int)` method, not if it was created using the `new` operator. It holds true for autoboxing because autoboxing uses the `Integer.valueOf(int)` method.

Answer (score 0):

a is a good question. As `Integer`s are immutable, the Java implementation doesn't guarantee that you will get a unique object for each Integer. Java uses a pool of `Integer` objects for small values -128 to +127, so `a` and `b` both reference the same underlying `1` object.

As for b, both Strings are instances of the same `String` class. `getClass()` returns the same `Class` object for each.

Comment: If there any specification-backed guarantee either that small integers will always yield the same objects, or that large objects will always yield distinct ones, or could future Java versions e.g. keep a hash table of the most-recently-boxed integers and cache any value which it notices is getting used a lot?

Comment: It's 5.1.7 in the JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7  Values from -128 to +127 must be cached, and other values may be cached if the implementation has enough memory.

Comment: As written, it sounds like an implementation would be free to decide arbitrarily whether any particular request to box anything other than an `int` -128..127 should return a new object, and need not be consistent?  For example, an implementation could start with `intCacheTop` equal to 128, count how many times an `int` gets boxed which is between `intCacheTop` and `intCacheTop*2-1`, and if enough values in that range get boxed, start caching values from `intCacheTop` to `intCacheTop*2-1` and double `intCacheTop`?

Comment: That seems allowed by the specification, though I suspect the performance gain wouldn't be worth the complexity.

Comment: Odds are that programmers would avoid writing code that boxed so many integers that performance gain would be significant.  On the other hand, keeping a count of how many new `Integer` objects are getting created wouldn't be very expensive; whether or not it would be worth the "effort" required to do so, from a performance perspective having the GC watch for cases where e.g. an application had declined to do its own caching of integer variables which related to quantities which were expected to be less than 128, but which had grown beyond that, might be a tiny-risk occasional-reward, scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already already aware, this is related to the autboxing/unboxing concept. So, when you compare the `Integer` objects , you can imagine the compiler automaticaly adds `intValue()` when comparing them - so it essentially becomes a primitive value comparison rather than object equality.

Regarding the String, that;s because it compares class/types, which is always a single (and hence same) one in the JVM.

Comment: That's not true. Try with Integer x=999, y=999 and do a ==. It returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of `==` and `equals()` is correct. In the first case, it is so because of caching. In the second case, the class of the object is always same, it does not depend on the instance. If it did, it would be huge waste of memory.